# Go relative path up and down in R

Tags: r

This is my folder structure:

```
projectFolder
  |      |
  |     subFolder2
  |
subFolder1
```

I have an R-script in subFolder1. How can I source a script in subFolder2 using a relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got the answer:

```
source("../subFolder2/myScript.R")
```